# The operator ^ is undefined for the argument type(s) long, boolean

Tags: java, xor

I am getting error when I am performing XOR (^) operation on long datatype in Java.

I am not sure if this is how Java works.

Here's the code generating error:

```
long a = 0, b = 0;
while (a < d) { // d is some value with datatype as long
    while (b < d) {
        if (a ^ b == c && a * b > max) { // error here (c is also some value with datatype as long)
            max = a * b;
        }
        b += 1;
    }
    a += 1;
}
```

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: == operator has more precedence than ^.  so use `(a ^ b) == c`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use parentheses like the following:

```
if ((a ^ b) == c && a * b > max) { // error here (c is also some 
                                  // value with datatype as  long)
         max = a * b;
}
```

`^` has lower precedence than `==` so the compiler thinks you're trying to XOR with a boolean.